# Retornar o id de uma tabela em outra tabela

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tenho uma tabela clientes contendo ID_CLIENTE, NOME_CLIENTE e outra tabela aprovação contendo CLIENTE_APROVADO.

A tabela aprovação está preenchida com ALGUNS clientes da tabela clientes porém apenas os NOMES dos clientes. Eu queria substituir o nome pelo id do cliente. Ou criar uma coluna id_cliente na tabela aprovação. Queria fazer isso em php. Como posso montar essa query do sql ?

Comment: Teria alguma hipótese de adicionar o campo Cliente_Aprovado na tabela Clientes e excluir a tabela Aprovação? Não vejo necessidade de ter outra tabela somente para aprovação. Qual a ideia da existência da tabela Aprovação?

Comment: Realmente, você pode incluir o campo cliente_aprovado na tabela clientes e o definir como um valor lógico.

Comment: A melhor ideia seria você criar uma chave estrangeira na tabela `aprovacao` e fazendo uma comparação com os nomes repetidos, e fazendo um update diretamente no banco, como na resposta do Levi Macedo.

Answer (score 1):

O ideal seria criar uma coluna `id_cliente` na tabela de `CLIENTE_APROVADO` e migrar da seguinte forma:

```
update CA
set cA.id_cliente = CC.IDCLIENTE
from CLIENTE_APROVADO CA WITH(NOLOCK)
inner join CLIENTES CC ON CC.NOMECLIENTE = CA.NOMECLIENTE
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro voce deve adicionar uma coluna na tabela `aprovacao`

`ALTER TABLE aprovacao ADD id_cliente BIGINT;`

Agora voce precisa adicionar o `id_cliente` sugiro que utilize um `UPDATE` com o `SELECT`, ficaria +/- assim.

`UPDATE aprovacao 
 SET aprovacao.id_cliente = clientes.id_cliente 
 FROM clientes 
 WHERE aprovacao.NOMES = clientes.NOMES and aprovacao.id_cliente <> null`

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma chave estrangeira para a tabela `aprovacao`:

```
ALTER TABLE `aprovacao` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_id_cliente` FOREIGN KEY ( `ID_CLIENTE` ) REFERENCES `clientes` ( `ID_CLIENTE` );
```

Depois basta atualizar os dados comparando o nome entre as duas tabelas:

```
UPDATE AP
set AP.ID_CLIENTE = CL.ID_CLIENTE
FROM clientes CL
INNER JOIN aprovacao AP ON (CL.NOME_CLIENTE = AP.CLIENTE_APROVADO)
```